# Optimal statement_timeout value Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there an optimal value for **statement_timeout**? Default is ca 1 second. But some "normal" statement takes longer time will results in an error.

What is the downside to set this value to 5000 or higher?

```
statement_timeout = 5000
```

"Setting statement_timeout in postgresql.conf is not recommended because it would affect all sessions". But WHY?

TIA,

Comment: What if you have mixed queries? Reports running for minutes and OLTP type queries running a few milliseconds? What is the optimal timeout then? Btw: the default timeout is 0 which means this is _disabled_.

Comment: For some reason my default value was 1000 (cannot remember that I set this value). But is 0 recommended? Pros and cons?

Comment: `0` is the default after an `initdb` and you already quoted the "recommendation". As far as the actual value you set is concerned: there is no "recommendation" - this will be extremely different for each application

Comment: So setting the value to 0 should be safe, because it is the "normal" default :-)